# x-bind with forwarded wire:model in a template element

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

Consider the following, in a blade template:

```html
<template x-for="(product, index) in getProducts()" :key="index">
    <li class="flex items-center px-1 py-3 rounded-md hover:bg-gray-50">
        <label class="flex items-center justify-between hover:cursor-pointer">
            <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" x-bind:value="product.id" class="cursor-pointer form-checkbox" {{ $attributes->wire('model') }} />
        </label>
        [..]
    </li>
</template>
```

I'm using it as follow:

```html
<x-forms.product-selector wire:model.lazy="activeProducts" />
```

When playing with checkboxes, nothing happens (i.e no event is fired for livewire).

Would anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wire:model doesn't work inside template

https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/919